# Detect Activity Launch

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, notifications, analytics

I am using an external library in our project. That library showing notification. On tapping that notification starts activity in the library.

I want to detect that activity launch from push notification to track some analytics data.

**Is there any way to detect those notification taps or activity launch?**

Comment: Use can use 'Log'.

Comment: Add some code there

Comment: Let create a new class that extends from activity in library, override `onCreate()` method, and after `super()` method, put your code that notify yourself about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you activity is already launched on notification tap. For detecting activity launch you can use [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks). In such case you will need to override `onActivityCreated`/`onActivityStarted` which includes created/started activity as argument. You can inject analytics component inside and send events about launched activities.

```
class AppLifecycleCallbacks : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        if (activity is MyActivity) {
            //...
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Valerii.. It is helpful. But, still I want to figure it out the activity is launched from notification or from another activity.  Anyway, I'll figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass some extra meta data along with your `pending intent` generated for showing notification. And parse same in your destination activity.

```
 Intent destination = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
  destination.putExtra("SOURCE","NOTIFICATION");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, destination, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
      .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo("App")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_like);

 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

And in activity level :

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("SOURCE").equals("NOTIFICATION")){
  // launched from notification
}
```

If your activity is already running your intent might get delivered to :

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, yes. When you create `Intent` for launching your target activity you can pass arguments to the intent and when Activity starts just obtain outer arguments from intent and if these arguments came from `Notification` do your actions need.